# How to get connection resource from PDO object?

Tags: php, pdo, odbc

I need to get the connection resource from already existing PDO object.
For example:

```
...
$oPDO = new PDO($sOdbcDsn);
$rOdbcConnection = $oPDO -> getConnection();
odbc_prepare($rOdbcConnection, $sQuery);
...
```

Also vice versa, I'd like to pass existing connection to PDO constructor.
I want to have the ability to work with PDO objects and direct connections separately.

Is there any way to extract connection from PDO?

Comment: Why do you want to bounce between a PDO and antiquated query mechanism? PDO can handle anything you need while also providing the additional securities.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it makes a difference, it is the RDBMS that manages the pool of connections internally and attributes the connection ids. Passing the connection object probably doesn't pass the associated connection to the RDBMS.

Comment: Brad, PDO has known not fixed for a long time bug with BLOB data fields and my DB backend that was based on PDO can't handle these BLOB queries. So I have to make workaround.

Comment: @user1581268 Do you want to use the PDO connection details anywhere in your code by passing the `$oPDO` as the object?

Comment: @user1581268 It will be enough to get some pointer to connection details once from PDO object

Answer (score 2):

I would think you have two choices:

1. wrap your PDO connection ( and methods ) in a class that you can pass around like you want. Define a copy constructor that will reuse the connection handle.
2. dig out the source to the PDO object from the PHP source and build what you need from there.